# MIPS overwriting/storing values in variables

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm having trouble with setting values in my MIPS program. 
    if x != y: z = 78 w = 5//Instruction to convert to MIPS

```
lw $t1,x
lw $t2,y
bne $t1,$t2, label
label: 
lw $t3,z
lw $t4,w      
li $t4,5
li $t3,78
```

Everything works up until I need to assign 78 and 5 to z and w respectively. There are values that are stored in those variables however, so when I try to set them to 78 or 5 it just adds 78 or 5 to whatever is in there. Can anyone point me in the right direction what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are not storing the new values onto their respective variables, you don't need to read them either because you don't need it to compute the new value (which is a constant in your sample).
- Also your branch is wrong, both possible outcomes just executes the next instruction. You have to use the opposite comparison and branch to a location after the *then* part.

i.e.:

```
  lw $t1,x
  lw $t2,y
  beq $t1,$t2, skip # branch if condition not met
  li $t4,5
  li $t3,78
  sw $t3,z
  sw $t4,w      
skip:
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Definetly worked thanks for pointing out my oversight.